# Show that $|P(A)| \le |P(A × B)|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $|A| \le |B|$ and $A$ and $B$ are not empty, prove that $|P(A)| \le |P(A × B)|$.

In order to do this, I must find an injective function between $P(A)$ and $P(A × B)$. I know that there is an injective function between $A$ and $B$ but I don't know how can I use this to prove that  $|P(A)| \le |P(A × B)|$.

I can prove it this way: let $|A|= m$ and $|B|= n$, so $|A×B|= mn$ and therefore $|P(A × B)| = 2^{mn}$. Now,  $2^m \le 2^{mn}$,  so $|P(A)| \le |P(A × B)|$. Is this a sufficient proof? However, I would like to know how can I solve this problem using an injective function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that if $b\in B$ then there is an obvious bijection between $A$ and $A\times\{b\}$.

Comment: Is my other proof valid?

Comment: @mandalo: Yes, it's valid. How sufficient is it remains to be decided but whoever grades it (and thus on the context in which you are writing this proof).

Comment: Oh but I think my argument wouldn't work if $B$ is not finite, right?

Comment: If you haven't discussed cardinal arithmetic of infinite cardinals, it would be a bit of a problem. But the general principles (all those in use, e.g. $|\mathcal P(X)|=2^{|X|}$) carry over to the infinite case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still trying to find the injective function, could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Do you know how to find an injective function from $\mathcal P(A)$ into $\mathcal P(B)$ if there is an injection from $A$ into $B$?

Comment: The function inputs a singleton of $A$ and outputs a singleton of $B$.

Comment: Are all subsets of $A$ singletons?

Comment: No. So I need to apply a function to the subsets of $A$, $f(C) = D$, where $C \subset A$ and $D \subset B$.

Comment: Right. So if $f\colon A\to B$ is an injective function, what would be an injective $F\colon\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B)$?

Comment: So I want to apply $f$ to the elements of the subsets of $A$ (i.e. $C$): $F(C)= ${$f(a)$}  , where $a \in A$.

Comment: Yes, your idea is right, but your presentation is wrong. You want to write $F(C)=\{f(a)\mid a\in C\}$ (on a side note[s], for having LaTeX show braces, use `\{` and `\}` and i.e. means "in other words", you should have used e.g. which means "for example").

Comment: So for my problem I define $F: P(A) \to P(A×B)$ such that $F(C) = \{(a,b) \ ∣ \  a \in C , b \in B\}$.

Comment: Well, that's one way to solve this. Note that this means that $F(C)=C\times B$. Now show that $F$ is injective.

Comment: Let $X,Y∈P(A)$ such that $F(X)=F(Y)$. This implies that $\{(x,b) ∣x∈X,b∈B \}= \{(y,b) \ ∣ y∈Y,b∈B \}$. Because $b=b$,this means that $x=y$, so $X=Y$.

Comment: Again, note that writing $b$ in the definition makes it a free variable in the ordered pair. So $\{(x,b)\mid x\in X,b\in B\}=X\times B$ rather than $X\times\{b\}$. This is an injective function, although not quite what my hint aimed for (but quite close nonetheless). If you want to have $b$ fixed in advance, then there is no need to put it in the definition of that set.

Comment: What about $F(X) = \{ (x, f(x)) ∣ x \in X \}$ ?

Comment: In this case it doesn't quite work. Note that your $f\colon A\to A\times B$, and so $(x,f(x))$ would be $(x,(a,b))$ rather than $(a,b)$.

Comment: I forgot to say I used your $f: A \to B$.

Comment: It was an unfortunate choice of notation. These were arbitrary sets. $X$ and $Y$, perhaps would have been better suited. $A$ satisfies the role of $X$ and $A\times B$ the role of $Y$. Suppose that $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $B=\{3,4\}$. Can there even be an injection from $A$ into $B$? No, of course not. But there is an injection from $A$ into $A\times B$. For example, $f(n)=(n,3)$.

Comment: Your answers are very clear, I think that what's confusing me is the notation of a function between power sets. I know that $F: P(A) \to P(A×B)$ inputs a subset of $A$ and outputs a subset of $A×B$. I also know that there exists an injection $f: A \to B$... I don't know how can I use this :(

Comment: Let's start over. Given an injection $f\colon X\to Y$ there is an injection $F\colon\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$. As we discussed, this injection is defined by $F(U)=\{f(x)\mid x\in U\}$. It maps a subset of $X$ to its image under $F$, note that rarely this is the only injection between the power sets, but this is one simple enough to understand. Now set $X=A$ and $Y=A\times B$. What is $f$ in this case? What is $F$?

Comment: $f(a) = (a,b)$ , where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Thus, $F(U)=\{f(x) ∣ x\in U \}$, where $U \in P(A)$.

Comment: Yes, but it is important to note that $b$ is *fixed* in advance for the rest of the proof. So now let's unwind the definitions and we have that $F(U)=\{(a,b)\mid a\in U\}$, or in other words, $F(U)=U\times\{b\}$.

Comment: I see, but why is $b$ fixed in advance?

Comment: How else would $f(a)=(a,b)$ be a function? If $B=\{0,1\}$ is $f(a)=(a,0)$ or $(a,1)$? Recall that functions need to be well-defined.

Comment: Perfect. So to prove injectivity: let $U_1 , U_2 \in P(A)$ such that $F(U_1) = F(U_2)$. Thus, $\{(x_1 , b) ∣ x_1 \in U_1 \} = \{(x_2 , b) ∣ x_2 \in U_1 \}$, so $U_1 × \{b\} = U_2 × \{b\} $. This implies that $U_1 = U_2$ , correct?

Comment: Well, if you've shown before something like that, then this is sufficient proof. Otherwise this is circular, since the proof that $U\times\{b\}=V\times\{b\}$ implies $U=V$ is essentially the proof that $F$ is injective. If you haven't shown that before, then a full proof (i.e. double inclusion) is preferable, and it's not that long either.